# How to send mail using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to send mail after processor. These is my step configuration:

```
public Step remindByMail() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("remindByMail")
                .<Customer, SimpleMailMessage> chunk(1)
                .reader(getCustomerList())
                .processor(new MailProcessor())
                .writer(new SendMail())
                .build();
    }

public class MailProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, SimpleMailMessage> {

        private String from = "aaa@oku.com";

        @Override
        public SimpleMailMessage process(Customer customer) throws Exception {

            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setTo("duyetpt@oku.com");
            message.setSubject("Welcome " + customer.getUsername());
            message.setText(customer.getInfo());

            return message;
        }
    }

public class SendMail implements ItemWriter<SimpleMailMessage> {

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends SimpleMailMessage> messages) throws Exception {
            messages.stream().forEach((message)->mailSender.send(message));

        }

}
```

And I have set these properties in `application.properties` file,

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.host=195.179.79.52
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=admin
spring.mail.password=admin
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However, I got the error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:323)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:312)
.....
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:880)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
.....
```

What should I do to send mail using Spring Batch?

Comment: can you show details about object `mailSender` , used in writer ? Also, is mail server a propriety one ?

Comment: i just @Autowired JavaMailSender mailSender in job configuration.

Comment: This is not related to Spring Batch . Make sure your email server configuration is correct. BTW, Spring Batch provides the `SimpleMailMessageItemWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

Its my guess by your error message - *No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client*  that below properties needs to be removed from your configuration.

```
spring.mail.username=admin
spring.mail.password=admin
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

In Spring Boot + Batch , I send emails using my organization's server without these properties as user name & passwords are not needed because program has to reside in organization network & that is the only security.

Its altogether a different story if one is trying to use - gmail , yahoo etc.

Comment: That means in Spring we cant setup security for accessing mail server?

Comment: No, thats not what it means. It means that your email server in itself is insecure & it doesn't need you to login to send emails ( its configured that way ) . Contact your email server infra teams to figure that out.